# Function to replace HTML at a certain time once a week

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace a marquee I have on an intranet site with another one, but only on Fridays between 8 and 12 for the Fire Alarm test.

Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmgh1985/7dKcN/ (the version I want to end up with is on there too, but more for clarity rather than it being permanently on the page)
and here is the jQuery I have come up with so far:

```
function firealarm() {
    var d = new Date();
    var x = d.getday();
    var n = d.getHours();
    if (n > 8 && n < 12 && x = 5)
    $(‘.marqueeframe’).replaceWith('<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5"><div class="falarm">The Fire Alarm will be tested this morning</div>><div class="falarm">The Fire Alarm will be tested this morning</div>><div class="falarm">The Fire Alarm will be tested this morning</div></marquee>');
}
window.onload = firealarm;
```

Comment: The logic should be x === 5 You are assigning x to 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x = d.getDay();
  and x==5 is are the changes for it to work

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. The main issue seems to be the actual replacing (if I take the time out of there, it still does not replace). Any ideas? And any ideas on how I can make it a bit less cumbersome?

Comment: Remove the existing marquee using the following ..
  $('marquee').remove();


use the following within the loop 

$(".marqueeframe").replaceWith('<div class="marqueeframe"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5"><div class="falarm">The Fire Alarm will be tested this morning</div></marquee></div>');

Comment: That worked a lot better, thanks. I think the crux of it was that I was using ' instead of " for .marqueeframe without even realising. My own fault for jumping between css and jquery too quickly ;)
(will try and remember to ^ this answer when I get enough points :))

Answer (score 1):

There were few issues with the code:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/7dKcN/8/)

Note the changes:

`if (n > 8 && n < 12 x === 5) -> if (n > 8 && n < 12 && x === 5)`

`$(‘.marqueeframe’) -> $('.marqueeframe')`

`replaceWith('<marquee ...</marquee>'); -> replaceWith('<div class="firealarm"><marquee...</marquee></div>'`

I have also removed `window.onload` wrapper, just because it's not needed on jsfiddle, but do leave that as is in your page.

Comment: some bits had slipped out from the code looking at that (as had the &&'s in the OP above). The really random ‘ rather than ' was causing me a LOT of problems though (have no idea why it did it either).